# How to restore the modification time of a file after changing it?

Tags: unix

I am modifying some files with the help of a script in Unix. I don't want the modification times of the files to be changed. I used the `touch` command but no use. Is there any other way?

I want the previous modification time of the file. Is it possible?

Comment: You should have saved the previous modification time before you modified. Just 'touch' will set it to current time. You need to use touch with a timestamp like mentioned in the answers below.

Comment: -1. your question heading says that you want change the modification time of a file and your description says that you want the modification time to stay the same.its misleading everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Touch is the way to go. Was your syntax correct?

```
[01:35:42 root@~]# touch -t 201107262235.34 foo
[01:35:49 root@~]# stat foo
  File: `foo'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: ca20h/51744d    Inode: 642445      Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2011-07-26 22:35:34.000000000 -0400
Modify: 2011-07-26 22:35:34.000000000 -0400
Change: 2011-07-27 01:35:49.000000000 -0400
[01:35:50 root@~]#
```

Answer (score 3):

backup:

```
# savedate=$(stat -c %Y filename.ext)
```

restore:

```
# touch -d @${savedate} filename.ext
```

Answer (score 1):

Capture the modification time before changing the file:

```
oldFileTime=`find theFileThatIsBeingChanged -maxdepth 0 -printf "%Ty%Tm%Td%TH%TM.%.2TS"`
```

Make your modifications, then use touch to reset the time:

```
touch -t "$oldFileTime" theFileThatIsBeingChanged
```